# Silverstripe image gallery issues

Tags: module, content-management-system, image-gallery, silverstripe

I am trying to install the image_gallery module for Silverstripe 3.0.3. I have already installed the dataobjectmanager and ran dev/build. All seems to be ok until i try to create a gallery page. I can see the option for image gallery page, but when i select it, I get a small popup saying internal server error.

After checking the console, i get the following information:

[image: header info]

I am working locally but cannot seem to get it to work correctly.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: surprised you even got so far, afaik DataObjectManager is incompatible as of silverstripe 3.0. don't know about a gallery module for 3.0 yet though.

Comment: oh i forgot, there is https://github.com/codem/DisplayAnything3

Comment: Great, will give it a try!

Comment: Has anyone managed to get it to work? i have installed it and can create the page, but when I try to add images in the gallery tab, it gets stuck waiting for the uploader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real Thing to understand here is, In `SilverStripe 3`, `ComplexTableField` has been replaced with `GridField` and `DataObjectManager` was based on `ComplexTableField`(http://goo.gl/fsFoz). So that's why it is not working anymore.

In summary, For simple Image gallery example, you have to

1. Create a page type
2. DataObject to holds image
3. create page in admin panel of type which you have created in point 1

[Using the Silverstripe 3 GridField](http://www.silverstriperesources.com/articles/using-the-silverstripe-3-gridfield/#) is the nice tutorial link for Image Gallery to get you started.

and 
[GridFieldBulkEditingTools](https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldBulkEditingTools)

Hope It will help.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it and comment back

Answer (score 0):

You don't need DataObjectManager in silverstripe. I was able to implement a rudimentary galery with minimal code in the Page Model:

```
public static $many_many = array(
    'Galery' => 'Image'
);
```

and

```
public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Images', new UploadField('Galery'));
}
```

Please note, that while this will allow you to add multiple images to a page, it will not allow you to oreder them.